# Help me score my cribbage hand

Tags: scoring, cribbage

In Cribbage, my hand was **2,2,2,5** and the cut card was a **3**.  I wanted to use the cut card with each of my twos for a count of five and subsequently one 15 for two points.

I thought the hand should have been 6 points for the three 2's plus 2 points for one 15 (2h+3, 2s+3, 2c+3= 15) however my partner said thats wrong.

Who is right?

Answer (score 1):

Your partner is correct.

The cut card is "just" another card for your hand for almost all aspects of scoring except flushes and knobs.  So, given a 3, 2, 2, 2, 5 you can score no 15's, and your hand score is 6 for the three 2's.

Comment: IF THE CUT CARD WAS A 5 AND I HAD 3 TENS IN MT HAND, WOULDNT EACH BE COUNTED AS 15?

Comment: Yes, the same way if you had 3 tens and a 5 in your hand. The difference is that you're not using the cut card multiple times for the each 15.